# How to use the set command to redirect output to another file

Tags: bash, scripting

Bash:
I was wondering how I could use the `set` command to redirect the output to another file.

For example, I would like to use the set command to re-direct the output to a file called "output", how would I do so?

I've tried using `set -h output` but it didn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking of `exec`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "script starting"

# make a backup of fd1 (stdout) as fd3, then redirect fd1 to an output file
exec 3>&1 1>/tmp/output.file

# your script here
echo "hello world"
echo "...and so on..."

# turn off logging
exec 1>&3 3>&-

echo done
```

Running that looks like:

```sh
$ bash script.sh
script starting
done
$ cat /tmp/output.file
hello world
...and so on...
```

You can use this method to log output to *both* the terminal and the output file, using a process substitition:

```sh
exec 3>&1 1> >(tee /tmp/output.file)
```

and other fancy things like adding a timestamp to the output

```sh
exec 3>&1 1> >(ts | tee /tmp/output.file)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`set` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) is not for redirecting output. Maybe you are thinking of [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

For example, if you would like to redirect the output of `echo 'hi!'` to a file, you could run `echo 'hi!' > output`.

Answer (score 1):

The `set` command allows you to set or unset values of shell options and positional parameters and it is not the right choice for redirecting the output to a file. To write the output of a command to a file, there are multiple ways and some of the commonly used ways are listed below:

```
command > output.log
```

> The standard output stream will be redirected to the file only, it
> will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it
> gets overwritten.

```
command >> output.log
```

> The standard output stream will be redirected to the file only, it
> will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the
> new data will get appended to the end of the file.

```
command 2> output.log
```

> The standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, it will
> not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets
> overwritten.

```
command 2>> output.log
```

> The standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, it will
> not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new
> data will get appended to the end of the file.

```
command &> output.log
```

> Both the standard output and standard error stream will be redirected
> to the file only, nothing will be visible in the terminal. If the file
> already exists, it gets overwritten.

```
command &>> output.log
```

> Both the standard output and standard error stream will be redirected
> to the file only, nothing will be visible in the terminal. If the file
> already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.

```
command | tee output.log
```

> The standard output stream will be copied to the file, it will still
> be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets
> overwritten.

```
command | tee -a output.log
```

> The standard output stream will be copied to the file, it will still
> be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data
> will get appended to the end of the file.

```
command |& tee output.log
```

> Both the standard output and standard error streams will be copied to
> the file while still being visible in the terminal. If the file
> already exists, it gets overwritten.

```
command |& tee -a output.log
```

> Both the standard output and standard error streams will be copied to
> the file while still being visible in the terminal. If the file
> already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.

```
command 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

> Both the standard output and standard error streams will be redirected
> to the file.